# How to add something after 1st, 5th, 7th occurence of element?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function to display WordPress posts on search term.
I am organizing some keywords on my site so they look like categories or tags, but with my custom styling.

```
/**
 * Display posts.
*/
function dispost($atts, $content = null) {  
    global $post;
    
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat'     => '',
        'num'     => '5',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        's' => ''

    ), $atts));
    
    $args = array(
        'cat'            => $cat,
        'posts_per_page' => $num,
        'order'          => $order,
        'orderby'        => $orderby,
        's'              => $s,
    );
    
    $output = '';
    
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        
        setup_postdata($post);
        
        $output .= '
        <articlex>
        <a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">
        '. get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'Medium Large', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) ) .'
        </a>
        <div class="text">
        <h2><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h2>
        <p>
        '. get_the_excerpt() .'
        <br>
        <a class="post-preview-link" href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">Read More...</a>
        </p>
        </div>
        </articlex>';
        
    }
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    return '<main>'. $output .'</main>';
    
}
```

I want to add ads after every X number of **articlex**, but I am not sure how to do it.
It should appear after every 1st, 5ths, 7th and 10th paragraph (**articlex**) for example.

Comment: For starters, please make up your mind, whether you want "after every X number of", or after every 1st, 5th, 7th and 10th - those are not the same thing. And what after the 10th - are we done, no more ads? Or does it have to start over, and if so - how?

Comment: It is not after every X, I need a function where I can put after which parts I want.
So it is to tell the function, please repeat this ad after 4th, 6th, 8th, 35th, or whatever occurence of particular element.
It does not need to repeat, however it would be good to know the function for repeating it in some future works too.

Comment: Just use a loop counter variable, and check the value of that for a match with one of your target "positions", via `in_array`.